# jquery animate() not working with css properties

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery `.animate()` to make the background of a div change if it is scrolled more than 100 pixels down a page. I am including jQuery UI, so there is no problem with that, and the code worked before when I used `.css()`.
JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#top-links-bar').stop().animate({ 'background' : 'linear-gradient(white, gray)' }, 500);
    } else {
        $('#top-links-bar').stop().animate({ 'background' : 'none' });
    }
});
```

Older JS (worked):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#top-links-bar').stop().css('background','linear-gradient(white, gray)');
    } else {
        $('#top-links-bar').stop().css('background','none');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/tcpfkuLe/)

Comment: I don't think `background` is an animate-able css property, but I do believe there maybe a jQuery color plugin that allows you to animate color (but I think its the `background-color` property you want not `background` and I don't think it accepts gradients... only hex values)

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate `background` but you should be able to animate `background-color` with the jQuery Color plugin, which is bundled with jQuery UI (see [here](https://jqueryui.com/animate/)).

However, I don't think you can animate gradients.

Looking at the docs for jquery Color [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) it looks like it only accepts hex (`#000`), rgba (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`), and some name values (`black`).

Answer (score 0):

Background , color and some other properties cannot be animated with Jquery itself

Only property Properties that can be animated:

```
backgroundPositionX
backgroundPositionY
borderWidth
borderBottomWidth
borderLeftWidth
borderRightWidth
borderTopWidth
borderSpacing
margin
marginBottom
marginLeft
marginRight
marginTop
outlineWidth
padding
paddingBottom
paddingLeft
paddingRight
paddingTop
height
width
maxHeight
maxWidth
minHeight
minWidth
fontSize
bottom
left
right
top
letterSpacing
wordSpacing
lineHeight
textIndent
```

Read more about animate and which properties can be animated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)

Comment: `background-color` can be animated, but only with [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) plugin. It seems to come bundled with jQueryUI... see [here](https://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Comment: @A.B Well he did mention that he is using jQuery UI and this plugin comes bundled with it, so he should be able to. But yes by default the list you provided is accurate

Comment: @zgood my bad i didnt read about jquery UI , good observation and thanks for pointing plus1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate `background` because it is not an animate property.

See the property list that can **animates** by css

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Answer (score 0):

Background property can't be animated.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. font, background, border) are not fully
>   supported. For example, if you want to animate the rendered border
>   width, at least a border style and border width other than "auto" must
>   be set in advance. Or, if you want to animate font size, you would use
>   fontSize or the CSS equivalent 'font-size' rather than simply 'font'.

Answer (score 0):

u can't animate background in jquery use javascript ad css instead.

```
window.onscroll=function(){

   if(window.pageYOffset>100){
      document.getElementById('YOURID').webkitAnimation='chbg 500ms';
   } else document.getElementById('YOURID').webkitAnimation='nobg 500ms';

}
```

add this to css

```
@-webkit-keyframes chbg{
from{background:a};
to{background:b};
}
@-webkit-keyframes nobg{
from{background:a};
to{background:none};
}
```